# JPA LazyLoading Collections transfered via SOAP

Tags: java, hibernate, soap, lazy-loading

I've got the following problem.
I've got an Entity which looks like this:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Teacher{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;      

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "teacherId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private final Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Now I've got two finder methods:

- findAllTeachers(): `SELECT t from Teacher t`
- findTeacherByIdWithDetails(Long id): `SELECT t from Teacher t JOIN FETCH t.students s where t.id = :id`

As long as I'm on server side all is good. 
I'm using Hibernate on a wildfly 10 applicationserver.
I've got 2 SOAP webservice methods, one method for return all teachers and one method for returning exactly one teacher by id with the students loaded.

Now of course the LazyInitializationException is thrown when I'm calling the webservice method for return all teachers, because the Teacher Entity is already detached.

Now here is my question. Is there any other option than creating a DTO for this Entity?
If I'm setting `@XMLTransient` for the students collection, I'm also hiding it when I'm calling the webservice method for the detailed Teacher.

It would be so great if you could help me out with this problem... I tried a lot and I know that it would work with REST by using jackson-datatype-hibernate. But it is required to be a SOAP webservice.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with an custom [XmlAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) that can handle non initialized Hibernate's collection, something like:

```
public class StudentSetXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Set<Student>, Set<Student>> {

    @Override
    public Set<Student> marshal(Set<Student> value) throws Exception {
        //PersistentSet is the Hibernate's implementation of Set that handle Lazy-loading etc...
        if (value instanceof PersistentSet) {
            PersistentSet hibernateCollection = (PersistentSet) value;

            //If the data were already loaded you return the collection 
            return hibernateCollection.wasInitialized() ? value : null;
        } else
            return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Student> unmarshal(Set value) throws Exception {
        return value;
    }

}
```

and add the annotation `@XmlJavaTyAdapter` on your field:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "teacherId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StudentSetXmlAdapter.class)
private final Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Baptiste Beauvais,
unfortunately now i get the exception: 
java.util.Set is an interface, JAXB cannot handle interfaces :-/

So i tried to use a wrapper class but I'm not able to produce an output that looks like the standard output for Sets...

Comment: You could try to make the Teacher class your Wrapper by creating a `XmlAdapter<Teacher,Teacher>` where you just copy all classics members and treat specifically the Hibernate's one as above before passing it.